# How can I store very small numbers in a list after looping through values in R?

Tags: r, list, append, decimal

I have analyzed current data (ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/download-todays-data-geographic-distribution-covid-19-cases-worldwide) from the European Centre for Disease Prevention and Control that keeps track about COVID-19 cases across months and countries. This way I would like to gain insights about the spread of active cases, but also about the way they relate to deaths related to the disease. My goal: to create a variable that stores the percentage of deaths per total infections for every day in march, divided by countries.

Here is my code:

```
library(readxl)
d <- read_excel("C:/Users/hanna/Downloads/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide.xlsx")
#View(d)

corona_de <- d %>% filter(`Countries and territories` == "Germany" & Month == 3)

# explore the data
library(skimr)
skim(corona_de)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(corona_de, aes (x = Day, y = Cases)) +
  geom_line(color = "red")+ theme_classic()

# deutschland, england, spanien, italien, frankreich, österreich
corona <- d %>% filter(`Countries and territories` == "Germany" |
                      `Countries and territories` == "France" |
                      `Countries and territories` == "Italy" |
                      `Countries and territories` == "Spain") #filter for month later %>% filter(Month == 3) 
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Preprocess data and create cumulative and percent variables
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# format dates
library(lubridate)
corona$DateRep <-as.Date(corona$DateRep,"%Y-%m-%d UTC")
# store in list for later
dates <- corona_march$DateRep
# store countries list to loop through
countries <- unique(corona$`Countries and territories`)
#create empty objects
active_cases<- NULL
deaths_cum <- NULL
active_percent <- NULL
death_percent <- NULL

#loop through number of countries 
for (c in 1:4){
  current_country <- subset(corona_march, `Countries and territories` == countries[c])
  # loop trhough days of march
  for (i in 25:1){
    # get new cases, deaths and population size for that day
    current_interval = current_country %>% filter(DateRep >= dates[i])
    current_case = current_interval %>% select(Cases)
    current_death = current_interval %>% select(Deaths)
    pop = current_country %>% filter(DateRep == dates[i]) %>% select(Pop_Data.2018)

    # calculate cumulative cases, deaths and percent active 
    active_cum = sum(current_case$Cases) 
    percent_active = active_cum / pop[[1]]
    cum_death = sum(current_death)
    # avoid scientific notation
    options("scipen"=100, "digits"=7)
    percent_death = cum_death / pop[[1]]

    # store variables in list
    active_cases <- append(active_cases,active_cum)
    deaths_cum <- append(deaths_cum,cum_death)
    active_percent <- append(active_percent,percent_active)
    percent_death <- append(death_percent, percent_death)
  }
}
```

Surprisingly, everything works fine except for the percent_death variable. For the cumulative deaths, the output looks like this:

```
deaths_cum
  [1] 1098 1098 1098 1097 1096 1096 1093 1091 1090 1081 1070 1067 1052 1039 1021 1009  973
 [18]  952  925  856  728  650  538  426  240  149  149  149  149  149  149  149  149  149
 [35]  149  147  147  146  144  144  141  137  136  136  136  106  104   82   55   23 6799
 [52] 6791 6785 6768 6740 6713 6672 6623 6587 6454 6356 6189 5993 5804 5552 5379 5009 4662
 [69] 4315 3842 3413 2788 1993 1344  743 2696 2696 2696 2696 2696 2695 2693 2691 2691 2691
 [86] 2668 2661 2649 2612 2575 2560 2408 2387 2205 2098 1929 1694 1370  976  514
```

But for the **percent_death** variable, it seems to stop after 1 iteration:

```
> percent_death
[1] 0.00001100083
```

Any idea what happened? Why does the append function work for all of the variables except for small numbers? Is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Your variable names are a confusing, and it's biting you. You have `percent_death <- append(death_percent, percent_death)`, but you want `death_percent <- append(death_percent, percent_death)`.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend switching to variable names that are distinguishable by themselves, for example `percent_death` is good for the storing variable, maybe use `percent_death_i` inside the loop. If all your inside-the-loop variables end in `_i`, your code will be clearer and you won't make mistakes like this.

Comment: @GregorThomas many tanks! problem solved and I have created more distinguishable variable names.

Comment: Couple other notes: rather than `\`Countries and territories\` == "Germany" |
                      \`Countries and territories\` == "France" | ...` you can do `\`Countries and territories\` %in% c("Germany", "France", "Italy", "Spain")`. And I haven't read your loop super carefully, but you could *probably* do it without a loop using `dplyr`'s `group_by`.

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a neat way to perform the computation with data.table which I would not have found without initial advice by Gregor Thomas.

1. change object names to more distinguishable ones
2. avoid scientific notation of small values using option()
3. use data.table instead of several loops to reduce complexity and make the code cleaner

```
corona <- d %>% filter(`Countries and territories` %in% c("Germany", "France", "Italy", "Spain") )
corona_march <- corona %>% filter(Month == 3)

library(data.table)
corona_table <- data.table(corona_march)

# for each country in corona_march, calculate the cumulative cases, percent_active, cumulative deaths and percent deathsbased on the dates
corona_table[, Active_cases := cumsum(Cases), by = .(`Countries and territories`,Day)]
corona_table[, Deaths_cumulative := cumsum(Deaths), by = .(`Countries and territories`,Day)]
# avoid scientific notation for percentages
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=7)
corona_table[, Percent_active := Active_cases/Pop_Data.2018, by = .(`Countries and territories`,Day)]
corona_table[, Percent_death := Deaths_cumulative/Active_cases, by = .(`Countries and territories`,Day)]
```